# faire ses preuves d'intégration au modèle social dominant

Tags: vocabulaire

Please explain "**faire ses preuves d'intégration au modèle social dominant**".  I don't understand what "**Gillette**" means here, either.

Pour avoir le droit à la parole, il fallait d'abord **faire ses preuves d'intégration au modèle social dominant**, « entrer » dans l'enseignement, à la Poste ou à la SNCF, chez Michelin, **Gillette**, dans les assurances : « gagner sa vie ». (Les Années, Annie Ernaux, pages 78)

Comment: [Gillette](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gillette_Company) is a brand name. What exactly don't you understand after using a dictionary? [faire ses preuves](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_ses_preuves). *Intégration, modèle social dominant* are all transparent words...  and [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/en/translator#fr/en/il%20fallait%20d'abord%20faire%20ses%20preuves%20d'int%C3%A9gration%20au%20mod%C3%A8le%20social%20dominant) gives a correct translation of the sentence.

Comment: Thanks, None, but what is "to prove their integration into the dominant social model"?  Thanks again.  --- tk

Comment: They had to succeed socially by integrating the dominant social model, i.e. getting a job as a teacher, or the Post Office, or the Railways (teachers, Post Office and Railway clerks were at that time – 50s and 60s – civil servants or equivalent) or for a big industrial company,   was considered a good stable job for the lower middle classes.

Comment: @tk What exactly don't you understand in the sentence? And what *do* you understand? *Search and research. Sharing your research helps everyone.* https://french.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

The whole sentence means that: if you want to speak and that people will consider your word seriously, you have to get a job that proves a certain social assimilation. The listed professions prove strong stability (even if lowly  salary) in state companies like National education, Post or big and well known companies like Michelin ...